# Logging (W3C logs) with IIS with.net core app (No Managed Code)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, logging

Is it possible to use IIS's logging with an asp.net core application? We've developed several .net core applications and they are all hosted under IIS so I'm trying to take advantage of IIS's logging.

Unfortunately, enabling logging with a No Managed Code app seems to produce no logs. Managed Code applications do produce logs correctly.

Comment: Could you please tell me which kinds of asp.net core application you have used now? I have used the asp.net core 3.0 MVC application with no managed code application pool, it could write the logs into the logs file.

Comment: Most are target framework: .Net Core 2.1. I've looked at windows event log as well but I can't see any errors related to writing logs. Of course, the log folder exists etc as the service does not auto create the folder.

Comment: Could you please tell me which kinds of asp.net core application you have used? MVC, react, web api or something else?

Comment: MVC APP .Net Core 2.1 and Web API Targeting Full Framework (4.7.2)

Comment: Could you please tell me which hosting model you have used? In-process or Out-of-process.

Comment: I've tried both, hostingModel="inprocess" and  hostingModel="outofprocess"

Comment: I suggest you could try to modify your application pool identity to local system. Maybe your identity pool don't have enough permission to access the log folder.

Comment: I'll do some more testing and see if I can shed some light. It would be nice if there was any logging saying "attempted to write log but cannot".

Comment: You could check the event viewer to see if there is any useful information in it.

Comment: I have yet to see anything in the logs. I think I'm going to create a new project with the latest framework and see if I can't get it working.